Query to fetch datas where current date is greater than another field plus one year
I am working on a php project with mysql. In the database i have a table that store users data and in these data there is the medical certificate. When i record the medical certificate i insert the release date (I know that it is valid for one year from this date).
Now i would like to fetch from the database all the users that have the medical certificate outdated. To do this, i use this query but it returns wrong result.. What am I doing wrong? what am I missing? I use DATE_ADD to add one year to medical certificate inside the query:
SELECT id, nome, cognome,data_scadenza_certificato_medico 
FROM tbl_tesserati 
WHERE CURRENT_DATE > (data_scadenza_certificato_medico = DATE_ADD(data_scadenza_certificato_medico, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
    AND rif_tbl_utenti = 1

id  nome    cognome    data_scadenza_certificato_medico 
23  my_name my_surname 2023-08-20


You seem to make it more complicated than needed Just try WHERE CURRENT_DATE() > DATE_ADD(data_scadenza_certificato_medico, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND rif_tbl_utenti = 1

tried but it returns nothing.. that's strange..

Please add sample data to the question, and expected results.

In your query, = is a comparison, and it will never be true (a date can't be equal to 1 year after itself), so the result is 0. So your condition is equivalent to WHERE CURRENT_DATE > 0 AND rif_tbl_utenti = 1

@Barmar, ok thanks now it is more clear but even without the equal the query doesn't work.. my guess is that i am using the date add function in a wrong way or maybe this is not the way.. are there other date functions that i can use to achieve my goal?

You're using DATE_ADD() correctly. Please post sample data or create a db<>fiddle.

What is the datatype of data_scadenza_certificato_medico?

@Barmar data_scadenza_certificato_medico is date datatype

Works here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wNrvDJNZDixwdWymsSGscK/0

You're missing the rif_tbl_utenti column in your sample data. Maybe it's not 1.

@Barmar thanks, i used your query and it worked! I also learned how to create a db fiddle ;-)

So what changed compared to my suggestion that returned nothing?

@KIKOSoftware ok i retried also your solution and it works.. i don't know what to say.. maybe (most probably :-D ) that i did a typo mistake with your query..
